# Como alterar um pull request de um fork que já excluí?

Tags: git, github

Fiz um fork de um repositório, realizei as mudanças e fiz um pull request. Antes de aceitarem meu PR, eu excluí o fork, mas pediram para eu fazer alterações no código.

Como posso acessar a branch no qual eu tinha feito o pull request novamente, mesmo com meu fork excluído?

Comment: excluiu local e remoto? se sim, so sorry só se tiver backup, se tiver local pode fazer um push novamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso só é possível pois o GitHub ainda tem suas alterações internamente, já que o pull request está aberto.

Com o origin configurado no remoto do repositório principal, você pode fazer um pull no seu pull request. Mude o número no exemplo abaixo, `1731`, pelo número do seu PR:

```
git fetch origin pull/1731/head:minha-branch
git checkout minha-branch
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou!